# Question about finite subcovers

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm having problems wrapping my head around the part with $\rho_i$.Here goes:

$A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, $\rho$ is a positive real-valued function defined on $A$. Prove: $\exists$ finitely many points $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\} \subset A$ such that

a) $B_{\rho_i}(x_i) \bigcap B_{\rho_j}(x_j) = \emptyset, i \ne j; \rho_i = \rho(x_i) $

b) $A \subset \bigcup^{N}_{i=1} B_{2\rho_i}(x_i).$ (For some $N$)

Since $\rho$ seems to be arbitrary, I don't see what should stop $min_{x_i \in A} \{\rho(x_i)\}$ from potentially getting too big for a) to hold. Also I see that obviously there is an open subcovering for A, but why exactly as stated in b)?

Comment: You can *choose* an initial, infinite covering of $A$. So you can pick a cover consiting of balls with radius $2\rho_i$. The balls will, in general, overlap of course. But if you pick them smartly, they *won't* overlap once you reduce their radius from $2\rho_i$ to $\rho_i$. It's a bit hard to visualize in $\mathbb{R}^n$ - I suggest you start with the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: @fgp Thanks. But from what I understand $\rho$ a random function on A. So what if $min_{x_i \in A} \{\rho(x_i) \}$ is so big that the corresponding open ball already covers $A$?

Comment: @fgp $\rho$ is some given function, and not something I can 'pick' as I like. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If there's an $x$ with $B_{\rho(x)}(x) \supset A$, you're done - the set you're looking for is $\{x\}$ then...

Comment: @fgp Thanks. I can create a finite subcover starting from the largest $\rho_i$, hence avoiding overlapping of the balls in a). But that way I can't control the number of elements needed. To me it looks like $N$ has to be $\leq n$, and the number of elements should depend on the dimension. How does it guarantee that there will be $n$ $\rho_i$ big enough to cover $A$ with only $n$ open balls? E.g. just one ball with $n=1$. $2\rho_1$ could still be smaller than $A$ long.

Comment: This is a typo in the question, I think. The $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ quite certainly aren't supposed to be the same $n$...

Comment: okay. That makes more sense then :) Thanks!